# Interface keys from array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to enforce the keys of an interface to be used from an array of strings:

E.g. If we have the following array:

```
const myArray = ['key1', 'key2'];
```

I would like to create a new interface called `MyInterface` that would force all `myArray` entries to be the keys of an object:

```
const myObj: MyInterface = {
  'key1': true,
  'key2': false,
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `keyof` operator for exactly this purpose.

```js
interface MyInterface {
  key1: boolean;
  key2: boolean;
}

const myObj: MyInterface = {
  key1: true,
  key2: false,
}

const myArray: Array<keyof MyInterface> = ['key1', 'key2'];
// or ...
const myOtherArray: Array<keyof typeof myObj> = ['key1', 'key2'];
```

You could also go backwards like so

```js
const myArray = ['key1', 'key2'] as const;

type MyType = Record<typeof myArray[number], boolean>;

const myObj: MyType = {
  key1: true,
  key2: false,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the ```[number]``` syntax in TypeScript?

Comment: You can learn more about this here @OvidijusParsiunas https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Comment: @emeraldsanto is there a way to have mixed value types? Some values are booleans, strings, etc

Comment: You can use "ReadonlyArray<keyof MyInterface>" if you need myArray as a const